# adding a matrix to specific region of another greater matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to create a simple 2D frame structural analysis program using Python. During the programming, a 6x6 member matrix is needed to be added on the specific rows and columns of a 12x12 zero system matrix according to its node numbers which are represented in system matrix too. For example:

```
system_matrix = [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
                 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

member_matrix = [[0.43 0.72 0.47 0.96 0.23 0.42]
                 [0.51 0.55 0.94 0.11 0.37 0.83]
                 [0.39 0.92 0.92 0.21 0.31 0.46]
                 [0.83 1.12 0.67 0.69 0.56 0.84]
                 [0.21 0.53 0.44 0.83 0.58 0.46]
                 [0.64 0.66 0.19 0.21 0.16 0.43]]
```

At first, I want to add (or place) a submatrix of member matrix which contains the first 3 rows and 3 columns on a specific region of the system matrix. Is there a method in numpy maintaining this process or should I write it on my own?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use slices of numpy to achieve your goal

```
import numpy as np

ma = np.matrix(system_matrix, float)
mb = np.matrix(member_matrix)

#ma[0:3, 0:3] = mb[0:3, 0:3]
ma[0:3, 0:3] += mb[0:3, 0:3]
print(ma)
```